# Can I get a core refund without an exchange?

Tags: parts, replace

I recently replaced one of the half-shafts on my Saabaru with a new aftermarket part.  I know that the old factory one I took off can be rebuilt, and if I'd bought a rebuilt unit I'd've had to put down a hefty core deposit.  Does anyone know if it's possible to get a "refund" on an old core without having bought a rebuilt unit?

Answer (score 3):

Parts stores take a deposit when you don't have the old part, and refund you the deposit when you return the core. Since you didn't give them a deposit, I doubt very seriously they will give you any money for it. You may want to try an axle re-builder in your area, CV axles are easy to rebuild and a lot of cites have local re-builders, they may be willing to buy it from you as they will be able to rebuild and then sell it directly.

Comment: +1. You're going to have to try it and see. If one auto parts store turns you away, the next one might take it.

Comment: Is there any online community for the model in question? You might find someone else who has bought a rebuilt unit but doesn't have a usable core one to return, and might give you a bit of money for it?